# Populating a dropdown with another

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am populating one DDL with another if we select country name in the DDL corresponding state must appear in another DDL below is my code

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string  st = (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex).ToString();

    XDocument main = XDocument.Load((Server.MapPath(@"XMLFile1.xml")));

    var query = from user in main.Descendants("country")
                 where st == user.Element("state").Value
                 select user;

    DropDownList2.DataSource = query;
    DropDownList2.DataBind();

}
```

but I am unable to populate the states in another DDL can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you post your xml format with data?

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your query as:

```
var query = from user in main.Root.Descendants("country")
            where user.Elements("state").Any() && user.Elements("state").First().Value == st 
            select user;
```

please note, I took the descendants of Root elements and check for state element exist of country and then check the state value with given value. If match found that country element will be selected.

And also this will return XMlelements, you can't directly bind them to `DataSource`, from that query you can select  country name and something and finally convert it to a list or array. the result of above can directly bind to a DropDownList

here is sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<countries>
  <country>Test1</country>
  <country name ="A">
    <state>Test2</state>
  </country>
  <country name ="B">
    <state>Test2</state>
  </country>
  <country name ="C">
    <state>Test3</state>
  </country>
</countries>
```

load the xml

```
XDocument main = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
```

Get country Names from from country element attribute

```
var countryNames = (from user in main.Root.Descendants("country")
                    where user.Elements("state").Any() && user.Elements("state").First().Value == "Test2"
                    select user.Attribute("name").Value).ToList();
```

### EDIT:

your XML:

```
<country>
  <name>India</name>
  <state>
    <text>Maharashtra</text>
    <text>Kashmir</text>
    <text>Goa</text>
  </state>
</country>
```

updated code:

```
var countryNames = (from user in main.Descendants("country")
                    where user.Elements("state").Descendants("text").Any(s => s.Value == st)
                    select user.Element("name").Value).ToList();
```

Comment: my xml lokks like this  <country>
    <name>India</name>
    <state>
      <text>Maharashtra</text>
      <text>Kashmir</text>
      <text>Goa</text>
    </state>
  </country>

Comment: i have checked your code but i am getting null at countrynames when i debug

Comment: st value is the text from first dropdown  string st = DropDownList1.Text;

Comment: I know that, when you debug you can find the 'st` value , if it is Maharashtra,Kashmir or Goa you will get India as countryNames. otherwise you will get null :)

Comment: yaa but when i debug the code at countrynames i am getting like Enumeration yield no results

Comment: for your given XML, last query working fine. I'm sorry. That's what i can do for you.

Comment: at countrynames i am getting count=0 when i debug

Comment: Can you update your question with exact XML and and sample DropDownList1 values?

Comment: @user1435482, Have you corrected `string  st = (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex).ToString();` to `DropDownList1.SelectedValue`?

Answer (score 0):

use this instead:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string  st = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

     XDocument main = XDocument.Load((Server.MapPath(@"XMLFile1.xml")));


    var query = from user in main.Descendants("country")
                 where st == user.Element("state").Value
                 select user;

    DropDownList2.DataSource = query;
    DropDownList2.DataBind();

}
```

You were using the index (1/2/3/4/5) of the item, not the value, I changed it so that you use the value (display member) rather than the index of that item.

Comment: i have checked what you have said but i dint get any result,when i check using breakpoint at query it says Enumeration yielded no results

Comment: Your solution seems quite small, can you upload it somewhere so that I can try to debug your issue?  Without seeing your XML and what not I'm not sure I can fix this... The fastest way is for me just to open your solution, or a demo project you prepare where you have the same issue.

Comment: ya i know the problem is with the query but i am unable to get it where can i upload?

Comment: MediaFire? DropBox? SendFile? Zoho? SendSpace?  Take your pick, but I'm not here for too much longer!  So be quick :)